# Mantain Session with HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, dotnet-httpclient, controllers

My application displays webpage via streams, for security reasons.

I have this code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.webpage.com");
Stream products = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
return File(products, "text/html");
```

And this displays the webpage via a stream, and all is excellent, so, I send data via POST, for example, simple login:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index([Bind(Include = "ID,username,password")] DataUser dataUser)
{
    var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();

    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", dataUser.username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", dataUser.password)
    });

    var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync("http://www.webpage.com", formContent);
    Stream stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    return File(stringContent, "text/html");
}
```

And all is well, I can login, BUT, the problem is when I want to access to another page, It displays me the message that I don't have an active Session.

So, how can I mantain a active Session using HttpClient? Is there any method or something?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Keep track of cookies. 2. Can you quote the 'security' reasons for saving files to disk and then showing them? Trust me, i highly doubt you add anything in terms of security that way.

Comment: Thanks @zaitsman, it's more like my client wants that, I know, isn't very good idea, but he wants it, it's like "if my server is hacked, they can download code!, only can see this controllers, but not the core code"